# How to wire AC motor for old fan?

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, fan

I have a AC motor and it's belong to an old desk fan, unfortunately I missed it's circuit diagram, so it would be great if you could help.

My AC outlet supplies 220V, and the motor comes with a 1.5uF capacitor.

As you can see in this photo, I have 6 wire
[image]
Gray and Red are together!

In this photo gray and green are shorter than others, 
If I'm not mistaken, these wires are related to the capacitor?!
[image]

please let me know how to connect the wires to AC power and speed switch.

Comment: Do you actually believe that every motor manufacturer in the world will use the same coloured wires for the same part of the circuit? Across the world it's doubtful that you'll get many countries adopting the same colours for live, neutral and earth. What chance is there for motors?

Comment: Wire colors are totally ambiguous in motors. Unless someone here has that exact model fan and has taken it apart, there is little hope of identifying the wires' purpose. GRY/GRN might be run capacitor, I don't know. Three of the other wires might be speeds, but again do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try measuring the resistances on the lowest ohms scale of your multimeter. [This](http://waterheatertimer.org/How-to-wire-3-speed-fan-switch.html) website has common color codes, you may get lucky:

[image]